# Difference between .GetInt32() and Convert.ToInt32()

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, int, sqldatareader

I have found some good points about Difference Between Int32.Parse(), Convert.ToInt32(), and Int32.TryParse() at this [`link`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32885/Difference-Between-Int32-Parse-Convert-ToInt32-and).

I was wondering what are the differences between these three methods and `.GetInt32()`, and whether `.GetInt32()` method should be preferred or not-preferred.

Comment: You talking about `SqlDataReader.GetInt32` method or something? Because it is too different than this 3 methods.. Read the documentation from MSDN first..

Comment: Yes, working with SqlDataReader.GetInt32. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[.GetInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getint32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is used to **get** the value of the specified column as a 32-bit signed integer.

> **Remarks**
>
> No conversions are performed; therefore, the data retrieved must
>   already be a 32-bit signed integer.

[Convert.ToInt32()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toint32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) **Converts** a specified value to a 32-bit signed integer.

[Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the conversion succeeded.

> *I was wandering what are the differences between these three methods
>   and .GetInt32(), and whether .GetInt32() method should be preferred of
>   not-preferred.*

The above three methods are all different and all of them are used in various scenarios. I dont think it is the matter of preference rather more the matter of **usability and requirement.**